# How can I add a button press effect when I am using TapGestureRecognizer and a ViewModel with Messaging to send a command?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use this template to create a button that's clickable for my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t:BaseButtonTemplate xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                       xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Japanese.Templates" 
                       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
                       x:Class="Japanese.Templates.Btn2" x:Name="this">
    <StackLayout WidthRequest="50">
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding TapCommandParam, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
                                  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <Frame CornerRadius="25" BorderColor="{Binding FrameBorderColor, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
               BackgroundColor="{Binding FrameBackgroundColor, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HasShadow="false" Padding="0"
               WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50">
                <Label TextColor="{Binding LabelTextColor, Source={x:Reference this}}"
                       Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
                       HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       FontFamily="FontAwesome5ProSolid" />
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</t:BaseButtonTemplate>
```

The button is used like this:

```
<t:Btn2 LabelTextColor="#EA4335" 
        Text="{Binding ABtnText }" 
        TapCommand="{Binding ABtnCmd }" Grid.Column="0" />
```

And in my ViewModel I have this code:

```
public partial class PhrasesFrameViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand ABtnCmd { get; }

    public PhrasesFrameViewModel()
    {
        ABtnCmd = new Command(() => MessagingCenter.Send<PhrasesFrameViewModel>(this, "ABtn"));
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TapCommandProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(
            "TapCommand", typeof(Command), typeof(BaseButtonTemplate),
           defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
           defaultValue: default(Command));

    public Command TapCommand
    {
        get { return (Command)GetValue(TapCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TapCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TapCommandParamProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TapCommandParam), typeof(object), typeof(BaseButtonTemplate), default(object));

    public object TapCommandParam
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(TapCommandParamProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TapCommandParamProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty FrameBackgroundColorProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create( 
            nameof(FrameBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(BaseButtonTemplate), 
            Color.FromHex("FFFFFF"));

    public Color FrameBackgroundColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(FrameBackgroundColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FrameBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty FrameBorderColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(FrameBorderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(BaseButtonTemplate),
            Color.FromHex("EEEEEE"));

    public Color FrameBorderColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(FrameBorderColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FrameBorderColorProperty, value); }
    }
```

I subscribe to the message like this:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<PhrasesFrameViewModel>(this, "ABtn", async (s) => await Btn((int)Settings.aBtn, 1));
```

What I would like to do is to create some kind of effect when the button is clicked.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could do this? Note that the effect could be a background color change or anything that would indicate to the user that the button was pressed.

Comment: If you want a button that behaves like one then use one. You could try to create your own animation etc but I'm not sure it's worth it. Just play with a regular button with transparency on top of whatever other layout you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Just a quick query why are you not using the button instead of label and frame

Comment: Not using a button because I want to customize it and I spent days trying to get text to line up with the button control and to get the size to be the way that I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it only in xamarin forms (without native renderers) you must subscribe in your custom button to the touch events. In these events, you can do for example a small-scale animation or change the background colour.